# Cambiar de JDBC DRIVER de postgresql en Genexus 16u7

Tags: genexus

Estoy necesitando ayuda con la incorporación de un jdbc driver en genexus 16. Yo traté de realizar los siguientes pasos pero no funcionó.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último intenté agregar el jdbc Driver en el classPath pero tampoco funciona. Sigue tomando el archivo viejo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para que el JAR se copie automatico tenes que crearlo como "file" en tu KB. La propiedad "Extract for Java Generator = True" y "Java Generator Extraction Directory = drivers". Con eso el JAR se deberia de copiar a la LIB del Tomcat.

Para lo del JDBC tenes dos opciones:

- "Use custom JDBC URL = true" y en "Custom JDBC URL" pones algo tipo "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_example"
- O, la que vos planteas es la de usar "Use datasource for web based applications = true", y ahi en "JDBC Datasource" tenes que poner la definicion de un JDBC Datasource de tu servidor de aplicaciones.

Ejemplo de JDBC Datasource en el Servidor de Aplicaciones Tomcat:

```
        <Resource name="jdbc/mi_conexion_a_db" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_example"
        username="dbuser" password="dbpass" maxTotal="300" maxIdle="100"/>
```

Esto va en algun "context.xml", puede ser el que esta en "../tomcat/conf/context.xml" o en "../tomcat/webapps/miwebapp/META-INF/context.xml".
La ventaja de ponerlo en el context general es que lo podes compartir por varias WebApps, y la ventaja de ponerlo en el context de la propia WebApp es que es mas autocontenido.